# How can send entire php array values on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, foreach

I want to send entire array information by the button click event, basically I store all information in the session send it on button, the problem is that just one value of array sent from session array not the whole array. I don't know how can I do it?
When I print the $WhatsApp_info it print complete array which item store in session but when I send on button one item information are sent.

```
foreach($_SESSION["WhatsApp_cart"] as $values){  
    $WhatsApp_info=array(                              
        $WhatsApp_name=$values[0], 
        $WhatsApp_price=$values[1], 
        $WhatsApp_quantity=$values[2] 

    );
    $WhatsApp_json=json_encode($WhatsApp_info);

    $link = 'https://wa.me/'.$phone.'?text='.$txt_final.' 
    '.$WhatsApp_json.' ';
}
```

Comment: button code:echo '<button  data-default_text="WhatsApp"  data-default_icon="" style="background:#25d366;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: medium;" onclick=" window.open(\'' . esc_attr($link) .'\')">'?>

 <span style="color:white"><?php  echo ($button_Txt); ?></span></button></a>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you don't overwrite your array in your loop. Create a new entry using the empty bracket methode.

```
$WhatsApp_info = [];
foreach($_SESSION["WhatsApp_cart"] as $values)
{
    // Add to info instead of overwriting it.
    $WhatsApp_info[] = [
        'WhatsApp_name' => $values[0], 
        'WhatsApp_price' => $values[1], 
        'WhatsApp_quantity' => $values[2],
    ];
}
$WhatsApp_json = json_encode($WhatsApp_info);
$link = 'https://wa.me/' . $phone . '?text=' . $txt_final . ' ' . $WhatsApp_json . ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your array outside of loop. e.g. :

```
$WhatsApp_info = [];
foreach($_SESSION["WhatsApp_cart"] as $values)
{  
    $WhatsApp_info[] = [
        'WhatsApp_name' => $values[0], 
        'WhatsApp_price' => $values[1], 
        'WhatsApp_quantity' => $values[2],
    ];
}
$WhatsApp_json = json_encode($WhatsApp_info);
$link = 'https://wa.me/' . $phone . '?text=' . $txt_final . ' ' . $WhatsApp_json . ' ';
```

Comment: This makes no difference? $WhatsApp_info gets overwritten every time.

Comment: Thank You @MLF for Your Quick Response but still get one item information after your suggestion

Comment: That's pretty funny. My answer has solved your problem and selected answer is another one that is based on my answer!

Comment: That's why you downvoted? Your answer didn't solve the problem before the edit. I tried to point it out so you could edit yourself. It didn't happen so I did it for you and even mentioned your name. It's just some points man.. EDIT: you are a university professor? Check your code before posting and be less childish about some points. I suspect you expect the same from your students..

Comment: That's ok friend. I think it's just a time problem. I was editing my answer just to add `[]` to array value assignment line while you posted your own answer before I click on Submit button.

Comment: @MLF my problem are solve based on edit suggestion by Wimanicessir after add [] this .By The Way Thank You